# No template for dependency: ConstDependency. When using web workers

Tags: angular, web-worker

I keep getting the following error: `No template for dependency: ConstDependency` When using web workers

Here is my code:

```
const worker = new Worker('./app.worker.ts', { type: 'module' });
console.log('this is the worker');
console.log(worker);
worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(`page got message: ${data}`);
};
worker.postMessage('hello');
```

It is having trouble on that first line. If I remove the `{type: 'module'}` it does not give me the error (but it also does not work). I have tried `npm prune` and `npm dedupe` but that did not fix it.